# commandLink action not performed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have the following XHTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam id="productCV" name="productName" value="#{productBean.product}"
                         converter="#{productConverter}" required="true"/>
        </f:metadata>

        <ui:composition template="/templates/mastertemplate.xhtml">
            <!-- Define the page title for this page-->
            <ui:define name="pageTitle">
                <h:outputFormat value="#{msgs.productPageTitle}">
                    <f:param value="#{productBean.product.description}"/>
                </h:outputFormat>
            </ui:define>

            <!-- Pass the categoryName parameter to the sidebar so the category of this product is highlighted-->
            <ui:param name="categoryName" value="#{productBean.product.categoryName}"/>

            <ui:define name="content">
                <!-- If productconversion failed, show this error-->
                <h:message id="error" for="productCV" style="color: #0081c2;" rendered="#{productBean.product == null}" />

                <!-- If productconversion succeeded show the product page-->
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{productBean.product != null}">
                    <p>#{productBean.product.description} #{productBean.product.categoryName}</p>
                    <h:form>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{cartBean.addItemToCart(productBean.product)}">
                            <f:ajax event="action" render=":cart :cartPrice" />
                            <h:graphicImage value="resources/img/addToCart.gif"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

At the top I accept a String as GET param which I run through a converter and then get a `Product` object, I place this in the `productBean.product`, that bean has a setter and getter for the `Product` attribute, that's all.

I then use this object to show info etc. this works fine. I also add `commandLink` to add it to my cart using AJAX. This refuses to work if my `ProductBean` is in `RequestScope`, when I put it in `SessionScope` it works, but will only add the product 1 time.

As best I know this should be a straight forward `RequestScope`, I don't understand why it does work with `SessionScope`.

I have read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked) post but I don't think I'm violating any of those rules.

For completeness, this is my `ProductBean`:

```
import be.kdg.shop.model.stock.Product;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ProductBean {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductBean.class.getName());
    private Product product;

    public ProductBean() {}

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your bean is request scoped. So the bean instance lives as long as a single HTTP request-response cycle.

When the page with the form is requested for the first time, a new bean instance is created which receives a concrete `product` property as view parameter. After generating and sending the associated response, the bean instance is garbaged, because it's the end of the request.

When the form is submitted, effectively a new HTTP request is fired and thus a new bean instance is created with all properties set to default, including the `product` property. This way `#{productBean.product}` is `null` for the entire request. The `rendered` attribute of a parent component of the command link will evaluate `false`. The command link action is therefore never decoded. This matches point 5 of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) which you already found, but apparently didn't really understood.

The solution is to put the bean in the view scope. A view scoped bean lives as long as you're interacting (submitting/postbacking) with the same JSF view. Standard JSF offers [`@ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ViewScoped.html) for this. As you're using CDI instead of JSF to manage beans, your best bet is the CDI [`@ConversationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/ConversationScoped.html). This is relatively clumsy (you've to start and end the scope yourself), so some CDI extension such as [MyFaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) which offers a `@ViewAccessScoped` may be more useful.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)